# Query limitation in DBO (Joomla 3.8.1)

Tags: database, joomla, dbo

I use JDatabaseDriver for interaction with database.
The next code I took from official Joomla Documentation.
[Documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase)

```
// Get a db connection.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query
    ->select($db->quoteName(array('user_id', 'profile_key', 'profile_value', 'ordering')))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__user_profiles'))
    ->setLimit('10');
```

Look at the last row in code above. 
The setlimit method is no exist in JDatabaseDriver class but it is declared in class - JDatabaseQueryMysqli.
Don't I  understand the logic or there is some mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Latest Joomla 3.8.1 setLIMIT does not work properly. You may go for alternative methods like
$query->setQuery($query,start,offset);